# C# Access Изменить поле таблицы DataGridView без обновления всей таблицы

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

Моя бд в Access связана с формой DataGridView. У меня получилось сделать методы сортировки таблицы (например, чтобы показывался только товар дороже 100 руб). И также есть метод изменения строк таблицы. После выполнения этого метода (изменения строки) вся таблица обновляется и у меня слетает сортировка... А если я не обновлю таблицу после изменения, то строка обновится лишь в самой бд, на форме она обновится только после перезапуска программы.

Код изменения строки:

```
   string CmdText = "SELECT * FROM [Таблица]";
   string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=base.mdb";

   OleDbDataAdapter dA = new OleDbDataAdapter(CmdText, ConnString);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();

   dA.Fill(ds, "[Таблица]"); 
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["[Таблица]"]; //вот эту строку я ищу чем заменить
```

Код сортировки:

```
  OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=base.mdb");
  OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Таблица] WHERE [Цена] > 100 ", con);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();

  con.Open();
  da.Fill(ds, "[Таблица]");
  dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["[Таблица]"];
  con.Close();
```

Comment: Сортировку как делаете?

Comment: Добавил сортировку в вопрос

Comment: `WHERE` - это не сортировка. Это фильтрация. / В чем проблема повторно раз использовать `where`?

Comment: Вообще.. Вы правы, такой вариант решения подойдет. Спасибо